# What's current best practice for migrating between AWS zones?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I've got a machine in the North Virginia zone I want to move to Sydney. I think I recall seeing something recently that made the job a lot easier - does anyone have any suggestions for the easiest (and fastest) way to go about it?

Comment: Snapshot the disk(s), copy it to the new region, create a new instance based on the snapshot.

Comment: Cheers Tim. Looking around I think it might have been 'Server Migration Service' I was thinking of (as the alternative to AMI copy) but that (SMS) seems to be aimed at a different use case.

Comment: SMS is for migrating servers from on-premise to AWS, not region to region. Create a Snapshot/AMI, move it, create a new server instance. I'm not aware of any other method, but that's not to say there isn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can just take the AMI and copy to corresponding region and then launch it there.

Follow this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-ami-copy-between-regions/)

Comment: Thanks Arjun; you don't know how to do it using Server Migration Service do you?

Comment: That particular service used for migrating servers from on premises to AWS. Atleast that's what I know.. I haven't used that particular service.